# Remove contour gaps from object

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, opencv3.0

Is there any method OpenCV provides or any other methods to smooth the contours:

[image]

Here what I want is the smaller gaps in the edge pixels i.e contours need to overlap and the shape of the detected object should come smoothly.

Here is another contour of an object detected; here I reduced the noise but still the contour is not smooth.  Why I'm trying to get smooth edges is so that after this can be divided into lines and curves.

The main thing I want is to jump the smaller gaps in edges.

[image]

Comment: Check the following examples: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NAIYz2Y4Dz4 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0hatQl2FF8w 
If you represent your contour as a set of (meta)pixels you can easily apply Gaussian  blur.

Comment: where can i find how its done, or source code?

Comment: Take a look at morphological operations, particular, morph close. You can also try blurring with Gaussian blur or median blur